# error warning message when i try to log on to a page using php and mysql

Tags: mysql

```
$result = mysql_query($db, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) ==1)
```

> Error message: "mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\registration\server.php on line 65"
>
> "mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\registration\server.php on line 66"

Can anyone please help me not getting those two errors, I'm trying to log on to a page but I'm really not familiar with the errors above

Comment: I don't believe that someone still use deprecated [mysql_](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql`  pass `connection object` second

write `mysql_query($query,$db);` instead of `mysql_query($db, $query);`

and you write `mysqli_query` for count row and use `mysql_query` for get result

so change `mysqli_fetch_rows` to `mysql_fetch_rows`

so its work

code like below

```
$result = mysql_query($query,$db);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) ==1)
```

or using `mysqli`

```
$result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) ==1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

syntax mysql_query(query, connection)

$result = mysql_query( $query,$db);

Comment: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE            and its showing this now

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql_query($query, [$link]);` documentation can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

So you would need `mysql_query($query, $db);`

Part of your issue is that you're also using `mysql_query` with `mysqli_num_rows`, and you need to be consistent.

That being said, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and should not be used in new code (and replaced in old). If you want a simple transition, `mysqli_*` is an acceptable replacement, which supports parameter binding and other more secure and conventional methods. That documentation can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php).

A tutorial for `mysqli_*` or PDO (preferred) can be found all of the place, but a decent one is [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysqli/mysqli_connection.htm).